# How much salt and pepper "was" or "were" added to the soup?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

Which of the following is correct?

1. How much salt and pepper **was** added to the soup?
2. How much salt and pepper **were** added to the soup?

In other words, should "salt and pepper" be followed by a singular or a plural verb? Please also explain why.

Comment: @tchrist: Off-topic proofreading? There's a difference of a single word between the two sentences.

Comment: @sumelic That's correct: all "which one is right?" questions are [offtopic proofreading](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/9902/2085). They don’t help anyone else and they should no effort. There might be an interesting question here, but work will need to be one on it first.

Comment: @tchrist: 1. which particular word is in question: "was" or "were"
2. what might be wrong about it: the grammatical number (this was identified in the old title, and I moved this information to the body and tags).
3. why it might be wrong: this does have to be inferred, but it's obvious that the reason for uncertainty is the presence of the coordinating conjunction "and" connecting two singular noun phrases.

Comment: jia103, i decided to vote  to close your question as a duplicate, but if you disagree with this decision you are still able to edit your post to explain why it's not a duplicate. Please notify me if you decide to do this by posting a comment below this answer that contains "@sumelic".

Comment: I'm not too happy with 'salt and pepper' being treated as a single enitity – I think two answers are required, so plural concord is necessary in this case.